# Where to install libraries manually?

Tags: libraries, c++

I want to install [SFML (a free multimedia C++ API)](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) on my Ubuntu system, which basically isn't a problem. But I wanted to know where I should store the files.

I can see, that Ubuntu stores my C++ Standard libraries in `/usr/include/c++` and so on..
My problem is, that I don't know where I am supposed to leave the libraries or is there no place which should be used for this and I can move the files wherever I want?

All I am looking for is just some kind of a way "how to do it right" but I can't find an answer. I want my libraries to stay organized.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib/` should be the right folder for this. It is the normal place for keeping shared library files installed manually from source code (as defined by [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_hierarchy_standard)).

If you build a library by running `./configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install`, it will *usually* install there automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was that kind of answer I needed :)

Comment: Also `/usr/local/include/` for the include files.

Comment: once you moved it there how fdo you make sure the whole system knows it's there? do you have to edit `/etc/environement` or something?